# Does any U.S.-sold brand of "100% pure" fruit juice contain added HFCS?

Tags: nutrition, united-states

The book [Deep Nutrition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0615228380) makes the following claim:

> ... your "100 percent orange juice" is doped with corn syrup. (Some FDA officials suspect that many fruit juices claiming to be 100 percent natural juice are in fact sweetened with high-fructose corn syrup...)

(Chapter 9, don't know page number as I'm reading it on kindle)

The author cites the paper, [Observations on Economic Adulteration of High-Value Food Products](http://ideas.repec.org/a/ags/jlofdr/27319.html#related)<sup>1</sup>.  There are a couple related mentions of orange juice in the paper *(emphasis mine)*:

> **Orange juice** and olive oil are food products often targeted for economic adulteration... (p. 1)
>
> Food scientists and chemists have developed a number of tests to detect the presence of illegal ingredients in honey... Similar tests have been developed to detect adulteration in **orange juice**. However, tests for non-labeled ingredients often are not able to accurately detect very small amounts of such ingredients... (p. 3)

But the basis for the first claim is uncertain to me.  And the second only seems to cast doubt on the claim, regardless of where it came from.

Is there any evidence that orange (or other fruit) juice marketed in the U.S. as "100% pure" may contain corn syrup, or other impurities?  Or is there at least evidence that "FDA officials" suspect this?

<sup>1</sup>The book's bibliography cites "Observations on the Economic Adulteration of High Value Food Products. Fairchild GF. Journal of Food Distribution Research Vol 32 No. 2. July 2003. 38-45", however it appears that 'Vol 32' was a misprint, and 'Vol 34' is correct, as the dates match up.  If I'm actually reading the wrong paper, please let me know.

Comment: I don't know about the sugar, but read this article about where the Fresh squeezed Orange juice flavor comes from, and its not the orange!...http://www.foodrenegade.com/secret-ingredient-your-orange-juice/

Comment: @Moab: Thanks for the interesting link... that entire site looks pretty interesting.

Comment: Breakfast has not been the same since I read that article.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. If this would be a common practice someone would be able to
   prove it
2. If somebody would find a proof it would most likely lead to a legal
   case. Such cases exist: see eg (1) cited in the paper you provided yourself. It is a criminal offense. It will likely happen sometimes, but that does not convince me that it happens by default

Some additional thoughts:

1. Pure fruit juice already contains plenty of sugars,  [in similar amounts to
   most soft drinks](http://www.hookedonjuice.com/), why would more sugars be added (unless also water is added)?
2. Regarding health, it does not matter whether this sugars come from oranges or from corn. Fruit juice is full of sugars - and should therefore not be consumed in large quantities.

> WHETHER FRUIT JUICE is “100 percent juice” or not is almost beside the
>   point — both kinds are loaded with sugar and calories. If it’s “100
>   percent juice” the sugar is from the fructose that’s naturally present
>   in fruit; if it’s “10 percent juice” (or 20 percent, or whatever),
>   most of the sugar is in the form of high-fructose corn syrup. Snacking
>   on sugary beverages all day long, whether they’re soft drinks or fruit
>   juice, is not a good thing, for kids or adults. Over-consumption of
>   sugar contributes to obesity and diabetes. Some common-sense
>   alternatives:

From the same site: http://www.hookedonjuice.com/

As a bonus a study proving that fruit juice causes obesity:
http://www.deakin.edu.au/news/upload/HBSFruitdrinks19032007_final.pdf

(1) Fairchild, G. F. 1993. Unpublished Expert Witness
Testimony presented at the request of the United
States Food and Drug Administration, Plain-
tiff, in an Economic Adulteration of Orange
Juice Case (No. 1:93-CR-19) in the United
States District Court for the Western District
of Michigan, Southern Division.

Comment: Please try to find [more reliable references](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5/faq-must-all-answers-be-referenced) than the website you linked, preferable from a peer-reviewed scientific journal. The linked website doesn't cite any sources itself, and on first glance it does look rather biased and not exactly trustworthy. You're also somewhat answering a related question and not the exact question that was asked (if HFCS is added to fruit juices).

Comment: Good catch on the case No 1:93-CR-19; I guess my PDF reader doesn't do a case-insensitive search, or I would have found that before I posted my question.

Comment: It seems that there _were_ numerous cases: ["These cases have resulted in numerous prosecutions, involving charges of conspiracy, mail and wire fraud, false claims, customs violations ...](http://www.justice.gov/usao/eousa/foia_reading_room/usam/title4/civ00139.htm)