# Is sugar toxic?

Tags: medical-science, nutrition, biology, sugar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How bitter is Robert Lustig's “Bitter Truth” about sugar?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/370/how-bitter-is-robert-lustigs-bitter-truth-about-sugar)

From the NY Times Article: [Is sugar toxic?](http://www.nytimes.com/2011/04/17/magazine/mag-17Sugar-t.html?_r=1&pagewanted=all)

Robert Lusteg, a specialist on pediatric hormone disorders and the leading expert in childhood obesity at the University of California, San Francisco, School of Medicine, alleges that too much fructose and too little fibre is the cause of the obesity epidemic, in his [youtube lecture](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dBnniua6-oM).

From the NY Times article:

> ... sugar has unique characteristics, specifically in the way the human body metabolizes the fructose in it, that may make it singularly harmful, at least if consumed in sufficient quantities.

Is the assertion that sugar is toxic supported by the evidence? If so, is the term "toxic" being used in the ordinary sense of "poisonous", or some other sense?

Comment: @Fabian: Thanks; marking this for deletion.

Comment: we usually don't delete duplicates, they may lead people to the right question that are just using different keywords to search.