# is High Fructose Corn Syrup linked to Cancer?

Tags: nutrition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How bitter is Robert Lustig's "Bitter Truth" about sugar?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/370/how-bitter-is-robert-lustigs-bitter-truth-about-sugar)

There seems to be some conflicting information about High Fructose Corn Syrup on the internet. Is there conclusive evidence that links it to cancer?  on a side question, is it true that High Fructose Corn Syrup is not allowed in food products for humans in some European Countries?