# Does any high fructose corn syrup remain in bread after baking?

Tags: environmental-health

I have seen bread that has the dramatic message "Contains no high fructose corn syrup" By reading the labels on other breads, I find it appears frequently in the list of ingredients.

Since the yeast attacks the sugar and destroys it during the rising process, any characteristics of the sugar (even high fructose corn syrup) are eliminated and we should have no concern about its nature.

Does any bread with HFCS as an ingredient still contain any once the cooking is completed?

The issue of sweet breads such as Hawaiian sweet rolls makes me pause, but I can only assume that there is so much sugar that the yeast does not consume it all by the time the dough has doubled in size (the usual instruction in bread recipes).  And, of course, that might be a different issue since it is the intention that there are plenty of sugar molecules remaining in the dough to impart a sweet taste.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How bitter is Robert Lustig's "Bitter Truth" about sugar?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/370/how-bitter-is-robert-lustigs-bitter-truth-about-sugar)

Comment: Is there a notable claim anywhere? If so link to some source where it is claimed.

Comment: Why would you assume that all the sugar is necessarily destroyed? I would bet sweet breads still have some, like [Portuguese sweet bread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_sweet_bread) or [Hawaiian bread](http://franzbakery.com/products/sweet-hawaiian-dinner-rolls/). Why else would they taste sweet? The nutrition label on the bread at the second link says each roll contains about 6 grams of sugar.

Comment: Yeast is not necessary.

Comment: Your last paragraph seems to answer your own question.